# I try push into nested array but if don't save it correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hi to all I am new in this, I post already an simile issue but now I have other one I get this object

```
 singleChat =  [
        {
            "chatid": 10000414,
            "connected": true,
            "index": 0,
            "jsonedUser": {},
            "membership": "",
            "messages":[
                        { "chatid": 10000414, "createdOn": "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", "isArchive": false, "isNew": false, "message": "great", "messageid": 3, "sentby": {"id":59, "name":"Omar"} },
                        { "chatid": 10000414, "createdOn": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "isArchive": false, "isNew": false, "message": "hi", "messageid": 2, "sentby": {"id":59, "name":"Omar"} },
                        { "chatid": 10000414, "createdOn": "2018-10-31T10:20:59.5000000", "isArchive": false, "isNew": false, "message": "hello there", "messageid": 1, "sentby": {"id":91, "name":"Ana"} } 
                        ],
            "opened": true,
            "port": 10842,


        }
    ]
```

I try put a new element inside the messages array when I submit a form like this

```
$('#sendForm').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
         var val = $('#inputMessage').val();
         var chat =  { chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: val, messageid: 3, sentby: {id:59, name:"Ana"} }

         var newSingleChat = singleChat[0].messages.concat(chat);
         singleChat = newSingleChat;

         console.log(singleChat);

     });
```

but I console console.log(singleChat); is give to me this

```
0: {chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: "great", …}
1: {chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: "hi", …}
2: {chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-31T10:20:59.5000000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: "hello there", …}
3: {chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: "asdasd", …}
```

instead of some thing like this

```
  [
            {
                "chatid": 10000414,
                "connected": true,
                "index": 0,
                "jsonedUser": {},
                "membership": "",
                "messages":[
                            { "chatid": 10000414, "createdOn": "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", "isArchive": false, "isNew": false, "message": "great", "messageid": 3, "sentby": {"id":59, "name":"Omar"} },
                            { "chatid": 10000414, "createdOn": "2018-10-25T13:49:50.9900000", "isArchive": false, "isNew": false, "message": "hi", "messageid": 2, "sentby": {"id":59, "name":"Omar"} },
                            { "chatid": 10000414, "createdOn": "2018-10-31T10:20:59.5000000", "isArchive": false, "isNew": false, "message": "hello there", "messageid": 1, "sentby": {"id":91, "name":"Ana"} } 
 "new message" ->{chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: "asdasd", …}
                            ],
                "opened": true,
                "port": 10842,

            }
        ]
```

what am I doing wrong or how is it that this should be done, I do not want to modify the object, just only the array that is inside of this (messages) thanks so mush for any help

Answer (score 1):

Really you just need:

```
$('#sendForm').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
     var val = $('#inputMessage').val();
     var chat =  { chatid: 10000414, createdOn: "2018-10-29T16:50:44.4900000", isArchive: false, isNew: false, message: val, messageid: 3, sentby: {id:59, name:"Ana"} }

     singleChat[0].messages.push(chat);

     console.log(singleChat);

 });
```

There's no need for a new variable.  You're just trying to update the existing array.  I tried to mention this in your previous question, but it was lost in the fray.

Comment: I try push it but when I console it I just get 4

Comment: Did you leave the assignment in there?  Look at my answer.  I'm not doing any assignment.  Updated to show the entire context of the submit handler.  @AlfredoIzquierdo

Answer (score 0):

You’re assigning the result of `.concat()` which is actually the messages array, also what you’re trying here isn’t concatenating two arrays. Since you want to add a new object at the end of the array, you better choose to use `.push(element)` instead.

Try with:

```
var newSingleChat = singleChat[0];
newSingleChat.messages.push(chat);
singleChat[0] = newSingleChat;
```

In any case I would like to recommend you not to modify variables outside the local function scope. Modifying global variables from functions that are accessing them through the scope is not a good idea, since you’ll have always to look into the function body to see that a unrelated (from caller perspective) variable has changed.

Also, given that `singleChat` is an array of elementS I will consider renaming it to `singleChats`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
var newSingleChat = singleChat[0].messages.concat(chat);
singleChat = newSingleChat;
```

try

```
singleChat[0].messages = singleChat[0].messages.concat(chat);
```